# How to properly use AsyncStorage in a Movie WatchList

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

First of all,i tried to make a watchlist for movies,a page that contains movies that you add.I can't get understand async storage and how it works within my code.
I've tried different tutorials,but I still don't get to make it work.I tried with the code that official react-native page has on their site,but with no results.

```
      item2ADD = this.props.navigation.getParam('movie');
      _retrieveData = async () => {
        try {
          await AsyncStorage.setItem('@MySuperStore:key', 'I like to save it.');

        } catch (error) {
          console.warn("data has not been saved");
        }
        try {
          const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('TASKS');
          if (value !== null) {
            console.warn("data has been loaded");
            console.warn(value);
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.warn("data has not been loaded");
        }
      };


      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          data : [] ,
        };
      }

      async componentDidMount() {
        const data = this._retrieveData();
        this.setState({ data });
      }

      render() {
        if(this.state.data!==null) {
          return (
              <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.title}>Watchlist</Text>
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.backBtn} onPress={() => {
                  this.props.navigation.goBack()
                }}>
                  <Image style={styles.backIMG} source={menuImages.back}/>
                </TouchableOpacity>

                <FlatList
                    data={this.state.data}
                    numColumns={2}
                    renderItem={({item}) =>
                        <View style={styles.fList}>
                          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Details', {movie: item})}>
                            <Image style={styles.img} source={{uri: item.coverUrl}}/>
                          </TouchableOpacity>
                          <Text style={styles.movieTitle}>{item.title}</Text>
                          <Text
                              style={styles.movieDate}>{moment.unix(Math.floor(parseInt(item.releaseDate)) / 1000).format("DD/MM/YYYY")}</Text>
                        </View>
                    } keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                />
              </View>
          );
        }
        else
        {
          return <Text>FAILED TO LOAD</Text>
        }
      }
    }
```

I just want to know how can I implement AsyncStorage to store my added movies from the item2ADD,it contains only 1 item that i need to store in order to make a watchlist.(the item which contains all details that i need for a movie).
I want to save all the movies with asyncstorage then show them in that flatlist.
I keep getting :
invariant violation tried to get frame for out of range index nan(on android simulator) when i click to add a movie to the list.

Comment: It is not very easy to understand your question, please put enough details so that you can get help quicker, please see this to understand how you can improve your question; https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is the problem you are asking but there is a few things that maybe causing the problem.

## 1- In your function `_retrieveData` you don't return anything from it.

I'm not sure what you want to return but what you could do is return the value from the `AsyncStorage`.

```
  _retrieveData = async () => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('@MySuperStore:key', 'I like to save it.');

    } catch (error) {
      console.warn("data has not been saved");
    }
    try {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('TASKS');
      if (value !== null) {
        console.warn("data has been loaded");
        console.warn(value);
      }
      // returning the value.
      return value 
    } catch (error) {
      console.warn("data has not been loaded");
    }
  };
```

## 2- You are setting state with the data from `_retrieveData` without waiting for it.

In you `componentDidMount` you set the data from `_retrieveData` but because it's a promise, you need to use `await` to get the data

```
  async componentDidMount() {
    //     added await
    const data = await this._retrieveData();
    this.setState({ data });
  }
```

## 3- The data you provide to FlatList needs to be an array.

When you call pass `data={this.state.data}` to `FlatList`, it needs to be an array, if it's not an array, you will have several problems.

Make sure that when you return the value from `_retrieveData`, it's an array.

```
//    value needs to be an array
const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('TASKS');
```

**You should also notice** that to `setItem`, it need to be parsed to a json, this means doing something like `AsyncStorage.setItem('NAME_OF_YOUR_KEY', JSON.stringify(DATA_YOU_WANT_TO_STORE);` and to `getItem` it need to be parsed to a javascript object, this means doing something like

```
const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem('NAME_OF_YOUR_KEY');
const value = JSON.parse(jsonValue);
```